# dataFrame duplication extraction row

Tags: python, pandas

The code below gives exactly the following Jupyter output:

date  open  high   low  close  volume

0  29/04/1992  2.21  2.21  1.98   1.99       0

1  29/04/1992  2.21  2.21  1.98   1.98       0

2  30/04/1992  2.02  2.32  1.95   1.98       0

size: 6686

no duplicates? False

---

date  open  high   low  close  volume

0  29/04/1992  2.21  2.21  1.98   1.99       0

1  29/04/1992  2.21  2.21  1.98   1.98       0

2  30/04/1992  2.02  2.32  1.95   1.98       0

no duplicates? False

size: 6686

What should I change in the duplication-extraction line?

Thanks!
fskilnik

```
checking = pd.DataFrame(df)

print(checking.head(3))

size2 = len(checking.index)
print('size:',size2)

print('no duplicates?', checking.date.is_unique)

checking.drop_duplicates(['date'], keep='last')

print(checking.head(3))

print('no duplicates?', checking.date.is_unique)

size2 = len(checking.index)
print('size:',size2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `inplace=True` to the `drop_duplicates` method or `reassign` the `dataframe` like:

```
checking.drop_duplicates(['date'], keep='last', inplace=True)
```

Or:

```
checking = checking.drop_duplicates(['date'], keep='last')
```

Comment: Hi, Franco. Worked as expected with the first modification suggested:
checking.drop_duplicates(['date'], keep='last', inplace=True)  what does it mean to reassign a dataframe, please?  (It is calling it by another name, doing the drop and then going back to the original name, for instance?)  Thanks a lot, by the way!

Comment: The assignment operator is the '=', so the reassignment basically is assigning to the original dataframe the modified dataframe without the duplicates. Welcome!

Comment: Ops.. I saw your suggestion now... sorry... still learning how to use stack overflow... (I voted for your answer, but I am still not "counted" as a beginner here...) Thanks for the "welcome". I hope to see you here frequently... LoL... and now I understood what inplace really means... very clever sintax possibilities...

Comment: Haha no worries, the usual thing to do is to do up arrow to show that you like the answer and the correct symbol to show that you accept it.